# How do i increase the size of the typed.js typing symbol

Tags: javascript, typed.js

The typing symbol is too small in typed.js. How do I adjust this?

[image: typing symbol]

I couldn't find any options that change the size/scale of the typing symbol

Also here is the typed code. Kindly adjust the code accordingly if you know the answer

```
var typed = new Typed('#typing', {
    strings: ['Programmer', 'Game Developer', 'Web Developer', 'Gamer', 'Designer'],
    typeSpeed: 100,
    loop: true,
    backSpeed: 100,
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can style the `typed-cursor` class to give it the same `font-size` as the typing element.

```js
new Typed('#typing', {
    strings: ['Programmer', 'Game Developer', 'Web Developer', 'Gamer', 'Designer'],
    typeSpeed: 100,
    loop: true,
    backSpeed: 100,
});
```

```css
#typing {
  font-size: 2em;
}
.typed-cursor {
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typed.js/2.0.10/typed.js" integrity="sha512-tQQXRDB2wEmuJGtFrmmoFYzNTq8StA1XJrfO0OQbbTxd9G0CwaTDL6/C1y805IlvBVrMwOqob1kf6r/2U5XXVg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<span id="typing"></span>
```